# Developing mixed C++ and C++/CLI for CGI and WPF

Tags: c++, c++-cli, interop, cgi, mixed-mode

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362434/wrapping-a-c-wpf-gui-around-c-cli-around-native-c), but given the direction of the answers, I figured it would be better to ask this question separately.

I need to develop a class library that can be both used in CGI (long story, sigh) and referenced by c#. Since both deployments must be able to be updated simultaneously, I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to work the CLI/native c++ interaction.

Since I have no control over the server deployment environment, all the code exposed to it has to be native, which doesn't work for WPF. As in the related question, I'm not looking for anyone to do my work for me, just to point me in the right direction.

I've looked into [COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz(v=VS.100).aspx), but can't find a clear, simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [swig](http://www.swig.org) to generate c# wrappers to the library then it can then be referenced from c# without any problems.

Comment: Though this isn't exactly what I'm looking for, it did lead me along the path to my eventual solution. Thanks for the input!